# How do I write text to a response in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a endpoint in my application which when hit I want to send a response to the client. I am doing it like this in flask.

```
from flask import Response
def heartbeat():
response = Response()
response.headers['Last-Modified'] = datetime.now()
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0'
response.headers['Expires'] = '-1'
return response(heartbeat)
```

This is throwing a error that call takes three arguments. What am I missing here ?

Comment: You should format your code properly! The indentation does not match.

Comment: I fixed it using make_response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
from flask import Response, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def heartbeat():
    response = Response()
    response.headers['Last-Modified'] = datetime.now()
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '-1'
    return response
```

then access "localhost:5000/" it will be ok.